# Getting random numbers in Java between two numbers

Tags: java, math, random

I would like to get a random value between 65 to 122.

How may I do that with the help of `Math.random();` in Java?

Is there any way to bound the values that will be accepted?

Comment: Googling the question title gives a great answer in the very first link. This should get downvoted into oblivion for "Lack of research effort"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static method `Math.random()` returns a number between 0 and 1 so you just have to multiply the result with the difference between you minimal and maximal value and add this to your minimal value.

```
int min = 65;
int max = 122;
int random = (int) min + (max - min) * Math.random();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `Math.random()` returns a number between 0 and 1 you can use a type like:

```
double d = 65 + Math.random()*(122-65);
```